# how to append every value from list to url and generate new url every time

Tags: python

i am trying to call every value from the list and appending it to url and generating url every time for the appended value

here is mine code

```
    myList = ['10026','10067','10093','10117','10132','10133','10464','10524','10654','10657','10658','10701','10809','10966','11153','11173','11327','11453','11470','11478','11488','11490','12733','12750','12754','12785','13053','13683','13895','14347','14420','14438','14452','14453','14457','14460','14755','16913','17460','17497','17500','17502','18007','18013','18058','18265','18711','18778','18779','18782','18913','19790','20105','20363','20609','20766','20770','21212','21216','21262','21471','21520','21555','21833','21946','21961','22115','22203','22994','23457','23800','24260','24590','25155','25649','25749','26021','26022']

    for i in myList:
        unspsc_link = f"https://order.besse.com/Orders/Search/ProductSearch?query={i}"
```

It just take only the last value

```
      unspsc_link
    'https://order.besse.com/Orders/Search/ProductSearch?query=26022'
```

Comment: You are overwriting variable "unspc_link" again and again in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```py
my_list = ['10026','10067','10093','10117','10132','10133','10464','10524','10654','10657','10658','10701','10809','10966','11153','11173','11327','11453','11470','11478','11488','11490','12733','12750','12754','12785','13053','13683','13895','14347','14420','14438','14452','14453','14457','14460','14755','16913','17460','17497','17500','17502','18007','18013','18058','18265','18711','18778','18779','18782','18913','19790','20105','20363','20609','20766','20770','21212','21216','21262','21471','21520','21555','21833','21946','21961','22115','22203','22994','23457','23800','24260','24590','25155','25649','25749','26021','26022']

unspsc_links = [f"https://order.besse.com/Orders/Search/ProductSearch?query={i}" for i in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one variable, called `unspsc_link`, it will get overwritten, for every iteration of the loop.
Instead you could create a new list with the resulting URLs:

```
myList = ['10026','10067','10093','10117','10132','10133','10464','10524','10654','10657','10658','10701','10809','10966','11153','11173','11327','11453','11470','11478','11488','11490','12733','12750','12754','12785','13053','13683','13895','14347','14420','14438','14452','14453','14457','14460','14755','16913','17460','17497','17500','17502','18007','18013','18058','18265','18711','18778','18779','18782','18913','19790','20105','20363','20609','20766','20770','21212','21216','21262','21471','21520','21555','21833','21946','21961','22115','22203','22994','23457','23800','24260','24590','25155','25649','25749','26021','26022']
unspsc_link = []
for i in myList:
    unspsc_link.append(f"https://order.besse.com/Orders/Search/ProductSearch?query={i}")
```

This will result in a list containing all the desired URLs.